# Is there the word макак (masculine) in Russian

Tags: словоупотребление, заимствования, composite-nouns

I've seen it in the news [web-site](http://lenta.ru/articles/2012/12/12/monkey/). It was used interchangeably with word макак-резус.

What is also interesting, in the same article they first decline both words like "самец макака-резуса" and then completely separate the word макак and use it as a first class citizen word. So, the second related question is weather it is a correct way to decline this compound word.

Comment: Could you please provide some usage context or the link to the site? Are you sure it's not a pl. gen. from the feminine form?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I added the link. No, it seems to be in nominative case.

Comment: `резус макак` is a loan translation of `Rhesus macaque`. Such loanwords are widely used in science but `макак резус` looks like illiteracy to me.

Answer (score 3):

Neither the dictionary of Ushakov nor Ozhegov has the word `макак`, but "Новый англо-русский биологический словарь" © «РУССО», 2003 has it and lists several species using this word. [Gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EC%E0%EA%E0%EA) doesn't list the word, but [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B) does. The only explanation I can find is that `макак` is used in scientific context, while `макака` is used in neutral, everyday speech. Also, it's better to say макак-резус, not the other way round.

Comment: Changed резус-макака to макак-резуса. Thanks.

Comment: What would be the proper way of declining this word: вижу макака-резуса or вижу макак-резуса?

Comment: @farfareast - Definitely, "вижу макака-резуса" is correct. You can see it in the web-site you gave a link to in the question, both words are declined.

Comment: It is not a prove yet if I see some example of usage on a news-web site. I would greatly appreciate a reference to the rule in some book like Rosental etc.

Comment: @farfareast - In "макак-резус" the second component, "резус" is an apposition to "макак". Typically, the problem is whether we must decline this apposition. "Mакак" is a wider term than "резус", that's why "резус" is an apposition.  In "Валгина, Розенталь, Фомина", chapter 276: Приложение - это определение, выраженное именем существительным, согласующимся с определяемым словом в падеже. (Apposition is a noun attribute, agreeing in case with the word it refers to.) If both words a declinable they must be in the same case.

Comment: I wouldn't automatically agree with you that "резус" is an apposition. This is because there is a strong tradition in Russian to put apposition in front (like "прайс-лист"). That's why I've made a mistake saying резус-макак. In this [wikipedia article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%81) резус is used as a main word throughout the text. Obviously we may need to find biologist to resolve our question. :-) The author of lenta.ru may have been influenced by the fact that the rhesus monkey in IKEA was a male. :-)

Comment: @farfareast - "Прайс-лист" is another case, borrowed indeclinable appositions go first, as in "HTML-страница", "веб-дизайнер", etc.

Comment: Maybe прайс-лист was not a good example. This [link](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_93) gives more examples of compound nouns in Russian but does not give a definitive answer to my question (if I understood right).

Answer (score 0):

The word макак can be directly produced from макака. No matter if dictionaries mention it or not, it is 100% understandable and mostly unambiguous. In the Russian language, we constantly morph words to adapt their meaning. Макак can be used to refer to a male animal, or mean, seriously-looking animal of any gender. For example, a monkey in dress, which is sipping tea from a cup and smoking a pipe, would most likely be called "макак", while a natural wild animal in the woods would be "макака", regardless of their gender.

And of cause such intrinsic details of language may vary from town to town.

Comment: Is макак to макака the same that обезьян to обезьяна?